# Api rest c# no toma la sobrecarga de parametros del metodo GET

Tags: api, rest

les hago una consulta estoy haciendo unas pruebas con apis en principio cuando los métodos GET estaban vacíos todo funcionaba cuando puse código adentro de los métodos siempre me entra por el get() independiente mande paramatros o no
este el el ruteo

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configuración y servicios de API web

        // Rutas de API web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetuserCredential",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{usuario}/{clave}"
        );
    }
```

y este el controlador

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Login/5
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string credenciales)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> get (string _usuario, string clave)
    {

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

asi la pruebo con postman

http://localhost:53481//api/login/marcelo/1122

Alguna idea de como corregir esto ??

Answer (score 0):

intenta probando así http://localhost:54515/api/Clientes?valor=8
Pasando el parámetro de esta forma con el signo de interrogación mas el nombre del parámetro y el valor

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).